# Flutter Blue Read characteristic UUID

Tags: bluetooth, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter blue to connect with an adafruit feather board and read in/write some values. How would I go about setting up a new characteristic that I wished to read from? I have followed the example but am having difficulty reading the double values produced on my arduino code.

```
 //Read Uuid

 BluetoothCharacteristic readCharacter = new
 BluetoothCharacteristic(uuid: null, serviceUuid: 6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9- 
 e50e24dcca9e, descriptors: null,
  properties: null);
//Write UUID
```

I am unsure what the declaration of the specific Bluetooth Characteristic I desire requires as parameters. Documentation indicates a uuid which I am unsure how to format?

Additionally, if there are any other examples of a simple project reading and writing values with a user interface established it would be nice to view.

Comment: Update: Solved the issue. (c.uuid == new Guid('blah blah..') is proper way for declaring uuid. Had to differentiate between service uuid and characteristic uuid. Used characteristic uuid and saved as variable.

Comment: From there parsed the int/byte array into the double values I wished to obtain. A useful example project for these applications can be found here: https://github.com/Sensirion/smart-gadget-flutter

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the UUID from BluetoothCharacteristic by calling `BluetoothCharacteristic.uuid`.

To filter the specific UUID, you can set a condition inside a for-loop that reads all the characteristics from a [`BluetoothService`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue/latest/flutter_blue/BluetoothService-class.html).

```dart
List<BluetoothCharacteristic> characteristics = service.characteristics; 

for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
  if(c.uuid == Guid('YOUR_UUID')) debugPrint('${c.uuid} found!');
}
```