# Using Flutter to connect and write to Bluetooth Devices

Tags: bluetooth, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new with Flutter and am just trying to make this work.

Am using Flutter Blue https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_blue

It connects though, just this issue when writing.

But when writing i'm receiving this message. Not sure what I am doing wrong though.

here's my code..

```
onPressed: () {
                  print("HEY write pressed");
                  var fff1 = new Guid("0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
                  var fffa = new Guid("0000fffa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
                  BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic = new BluetoothCharacteristic(uuid: fffa, serviceUuid: fff1, descriptors: null, properties: null);
                  _writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
               },
```

PlatformException(locateCharacteristic, service could not be located on the device, null)

I've tried following this post.
[Flutter Blue Read characteristic UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932757/flutter-blue-read-characteristic-uuid)

In production I would probably save the UUID as variables, but the effect should be similar..

If anyone has any guidance or tips that would be super welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right but the device you want to connect to doesnt contain this service :`var fff1 = new Guid("0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");`

Check which services exist in the device you want to connect to.

Comment: No it is not a reason. flutter_blue has not the best exception handling. I have same problem with service taken from device, its weird because when i got chars with id f.e. 0x0 one second later my app tells that there is no this char on device.